# can not insert to mongodb using express

Tags: node.js, express, post, routes, insert

I use in `app.js`:

```
const express = require("express");
const app=express();
const _route=require('./router/router.js')
require('dotenv').config();
require('./Database/config.js');
const port_=process.env.PORT|| 8080;


app.use(_route);
app.listen(port_,'localhost',()=>{ console.log(`App run on port ${port_}`)});
```

and write post method in other file named router:

```
const express=require('express');
const product=require('../model/model.js');
const router=express.Router();

router.post('/insert',async(req,res)=>{
    const newProduct=new product({
        name:'GLX SHAHIN 3',
        id:1,
        description:'Newest iranian phone'
    });
    try{
        await newProduct.save();
        res.send(`Inserted : ${newProduct}`);
    }
    catch(err){
        res.send(err);
    }
    });

module.exports=router;
```

and define connection string to connect to mongodb as follow:

```
'use stric'
require('dotenv').config();
const mongoose=require('mongoose');
const port_=process.env.PORT|| 8080;
 const connectionString=`mongodb://localhost:${port_}:sale`;


mongoose.connect(connectionString,(err)=>{
    (err===true)? console.log('Fail to connect to mongodb'):console.log('Connect success.');
});

module.exports=mongoose;
```

in `router.js` file i want insert to database. when i enter `localhost:3000/insert` get `can not get/insert` message.
i use `express().post` and `express.router().post` but get this error.
router file in which routing code written, is not in root of project.
what is meaning of this error?

Comment: Are you using Postman or calling this API by typing url in browser address bar?

Comment: Your mongodb connection does not work, `err` will never be true, therefore you dont see the error message, mongodb listen by default on port 27017 and not 8080

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have two issues here. First, you do not have an 'insert' endpoint set up. Try something like this:

```js
router.post('/insert',async(req,res)=>{
    // rest of code
});

module.exports = router;
```

Second, you are trying to GET this POST route. Make sure your fetch (or whatever you are using) us specified as a POST request.

Comment: i try this. but not work

Comment: @RezaRastgoo what does your request look like?